# How to get a Custom Attribute for all derived classes of a class in Windows Store Apps

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I have my

```
class BaseClass
{

}
```

and two subclasses like this:

```
[PostTransformer("test", Precedence=5)]
class SubClassA : BaseClass
{

}
```

and one attribute

```
[System.AttributeUsage(System.AttributeTargets.Class)]
public class PostTransformerAttribute : Attribute
{
    public int Precedence;
    public string Title;

    public PostTransformerAttribute(string Title)
    {
        this.Title = Title;
        Precedence = int.MaxValue;
    }

}
```

How do I get all the attributes of type `PostTransformerAttribute` of all subclasses of BaseClass?

i have tried:

```
var test = typeof(BaseClass).GetTypeInfo().GetCustomAttributes<PostTransformerAttribute>();
```

but it returned an empty array.

Answer (score 4):

Yes it's null, you're currently trying to get the attributes for the base class only.

You want to enumerate the list of all types that inherit from your base class.

I.e. something like:

```
var baseType = typeof(BaseClass);
var types = Assembly
    .GetExecutingAssembly()
    .GetTypes()
    .Where(z => baseType.IsAssignableFrom(t) && t.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(PostTransformerAttribute), true).Any());
```

(not actually tested, but here's the idea)

Comment: Dont think GetExecutingAssembly is there for store apps. but i get the idea.

Comment: Added an answer with the working method for windows store apps.

Answer (score 1):

```
    public static void loadTransformers()
    {
        var baseType = typeof(BaseClass).GetTypeInfo();
        var attributes = baseType.Assembly.DefinedTypes.Where(
            z => baseType.IsAssignableFrom(z))
            .SelectMany(t => t.GetCustomAttributes<PostTransformerAttribute>(false));


    }
```

This works for window store apps.